# Since iOS8 we should use CloudKit for all iCloud apps?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I've noticed a lot of people creating iCloud apps using Obj-C and importing .h etc. To a noob like me it seems very complex since I've been using Swift from the beginning. People say iCloud apps can be created using only Swift and CloudKit exclusively. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually CloudKit is a layer on top of iCloud. With CloudKit you can work with structural data. With iCloud you probably mean 'iCloud document storage'? In both cases you will be able to do this both with Swift and Objective C. iCloud document storage exists longer, that's probably why most samples are in Objective C.

With CloudKit you will be able to handle data records and files (as CKAsset). That data will be bound to the containers that you registered in your app. You will not be able to access data of other app's (unless the app is yours and you added the container)

If you want to decide when to use CloudKit or iCloud document storage, then have a look at table 1-1 at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW1

If you want to have a look at a sample app that is using Swift and CloudKit, then have a look at this complete functional chat application http://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao

Comment: Thanks Edwin. Good to know. I'd upvote you but members without 15 aren't allowed :(

Answer (score -2):

Yes this is possible.  Assuming you have an apple developer account, log in here: developer.apple.com, and if you click on the resources tab, you will be presented with information on this topic, as well as forums relating to this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!  Yes I have an account. That's great news.  Can everything that once used Obj-C now be made exclusively using Swift and various Apple frameworks? I tried to up-vote your answer but I can't because I'm a new member :(

Comment: Ok. I just recently became an apple developer as well. Apple has made their new language completely comparable with all their available 'kits'. From what I heard, some kits, like watch kit, can only be made using Swift. :)

Comment: Dude, why did you make me lose reputation? I answered your question generally because you provided very general information in your information

Comment: That was not me. Relax. I didn't touch the reputation button. Even if I wanted to I cannot affect the reputation button because I am new. New members can't use it.